# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) ajax xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have tried the ajax POST method. and below is my code

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#cloneform').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "my server url",
                data     : { inputxml: escape("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><document-id>my data</document-id>") },
                dataType : "text/xml",
                contentType: "application/xml",
                success  : function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error    : function() {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            });
    });
}
);
```

and I tried the same using the postman i got the response as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-id>data for server</document-id>
```

but  with javascript i am getting `Internal server Error`.

Can anyone figure our error?

Thanks
pkalyan

Comment: Where is your server url ? It shows that either you mistyped url or at the backend your url expecting other than what you sending.

Comment: We can't possibly debug a server-side error without the server-side code.

Comment: Did  you check the error at backend ?

Comment: @Nishith Chaturvedi well when i entered server url, but here i haven't entered it.

Comment: And as for server-side code is works as I can test the POST method with Header, body as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-id>d297db8e0f0954963397c27b6098e3278c583a46</document-id> and i am getting the responce as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-id>77fbafd85eb642fa6d9711eef841a87bbdc208cf</document-id> @Siguza

Comment: @pkalyan26 Your `Internal server Error` disagrees with you.

Answer (score 0):

"Internal server error" doesn't tell us much. Just that something your server side code tried to do threw an error. You should debug it on the server.

That said:

```
data     : { inputxml: escape("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><document-id>my data</document-id>") },
```

`escape` is the old, broken way to encode data for URLs. You aren't encoding data for URLs. Don't use it here.

```
dataType : "text/xml",
```

`dataType` describes the data you expect back from the server. `text/xml` is not a valid value for it. `text` is and `xml` is.

```
contentType: "application/xml",
```

This is **probably** the cause of your problem.

You are claiming to send an XML formatted request. This is a lie. You are passing `data` an object, so jQuery will URL Form Encode it.

Remove this line or change your `data` so it is a string of XML.